# Problem with VSCode and Python on a Mac

Tags: mac, error, python

I am trying to use VS Code to program in Python on my Mac. I keep getting the following error when I run my program in VS Code:

```
python -u "/Users/davidcfeola/Desktop/Python/Segmented Turning Data.py"
bash: uname: command not found
bash: sed: command not found
```

Can you help?

Comment: Do you only get that error when running that piece of Python code or all Python scripts give that error?

Comment: I have never been able to run any script without getting this error. Thanks

Comment: Have you installed python?

Comment: Yes, version 3.11.1. I can script in Interactive Mode, but not in VS Code due to the above error.

Comment: How did you install Python? Have you setup VSCode for Python? See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Comment: What did you add to your `bash` startup?  Since `uname` and `sed` somehow are not found, your `$PATH` is not set correctly.

Comment: How do I set it up correctly? I have very little understanding of shells and the terminal.